# pivottabel in xpages

Tags: xpages

I've been looking for a way to get pivottable functionality in Xpages.
What I found :

First :
[Pivot tables with Openlink Ajax Toolkit](http://www.intec.co.uk/pivot-tables-in-xpages-with-openlink-ajax-toolkit/)

If Paul could provide a sample nsf file to have a look at this would be nice, since I don't know exactly how to implement this with existing notes data.

Second : [Pivot.js](http://rjackson.github.com/pivot.js/)

This uses JQuery.  The problem here is that it starts from CSV or JSON data. How can we use notes data ... If someone could provide a working sample to have a look at ...

Answer (score 0):

Scott Good and I did a 2 hour presentation on using AJAX and JSON with Domino at Lotusphere 2009 which he repeated at Midwest Lotus User Group Conference in Chicago in August, 2009. The slides and examples are linked to Scott's blog [here](http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/d6plinks/SGOD-7NHRKR) and [here](http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/d6plinks/SGOD-7VBNUD).

/Newbs

Answer (score 0):

In that example I think I just hard-coded the values passed to the CSJS function. You would need to compute the values, either in a Computed Field control or as SSJS within the CSJS function. The format, I think, was a JSON object, so the SSJS just needs to return that same format. A Computed Field is probably easier, and certainly easier to debug. You can see it in action on the Dojo charting examples either on my blog or the Lotus Domino Application Development wiki.